# Returning "NO" instead of "YES" in recursive function

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to solve the problem of whether a number can be created from a list of numbers using math operations. So 42 would be

```
42 = 4 * 20 - 40 + 3 - 1
```

This is the code, I have used recursion and I'm not sure where it's going wrong because I cannot see 42 in the output. I have attached a snippet of the output.

```
nums = "40 1 3 4 20"
nums = [int(x) for x in nums.split(" ")]

def num_ops(n, nums):
    if (len(nums) == 1):
        return (nums[0] == n)
    elif (len(nums) == 2):
        a, b = nums[0], nums[1]
        return (
            num_ops(n, [a*b])
            or num_ops(n, [a+b])
            or num_ops(n, [a-b])
            or (b != 0 and num_ops(n, [a / b]))
    )
            
    else:       
        for x in range(len(nums) - 1):
            for y in range(len(nums) - 1):            
                if (x != y):
                    a, b = nums[x], nums[y]

                    temp = nums.copy()
                    temp.remove(a)
                    temp.remove(b)

                    return (
                        num_ops(n, [a*b] + temp)
                        or num_ops(n, [a+b] + temp)
                        or num_ops(n, [a-b] + temp)
                        or (b != 0 and num_ops(n, [a/b] + temp))
                    )
                
                
if (num_ops(42, nums)):
    print("YES", end="")
else:
    print("NO", end="")
```

First few lines of the output

```
[40, 1, 3, 4, 20] 
[40, 3, 4, 20] 
[120, 4, 20] 
[480, 20] 
[9600]
[500] 
[460] 
[24.0] 
[124, 20] 
[2480] 
[144] 
[104] 
[6.2] 
[116, 20] 
[2320] 
[136] 
[96]
[5.8] 
[30.0, 20] 
[600.0] 
[50.0] 
[10.0] 
[1.5]
[43, 4, 20] 
[172, 20] 
[3440] 
[192] 
[152]
[8.6]
[47, 20] 
[940]
[67]
[27] 
[2.35]
[39, 20] 
[780]
[59]
[19]
[1.95] 
[10.75, 20] 
[215.0] 
[30.75] 
[-9.25] 
[0.5375]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning the string `"YES"`, you can use boolean values `True` and `False` and lazy boolean operators `or` and `and`.

```
if (len(nums) == 1):
    return (nums[0] == n)
elif (len(nums) == 2):
    a, b = nums[0], nums[1]
    return (
      num_ops(n, [a*b])
      or num_ops(n, [a+b])
      or num_ops(n, [a-b])
      or (b != 0 and num_ops(n, [a / b]))
    )
```

**Explanation**
`num_ops(...) or num_ops(...) or num_ops(...)` is `True` if at least one of the `num_ops(...)` is `True`; it's `False` if they are all `False`.

Moreover, in the expression `num_ops(...) or num_ops(...)`, evaluation is "lazy": the second `num_ops(...)` is only evaluated if the first is `False`. Similarly, in the expression `(b != 0 and num_ops(n, [a / b]))`, the call to `num_ops` is only evaluated if `b` is not zero.

Comment: Well, I only rewrote the `if (len(nums) == 1)` and `elif (len(nums) == 2)` parts. You need to rewrite the `else` part accordingly.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense on paper, but sadly it doesn't work! The test 'nums' i use should return True @Stef

Comment: My bad, I have changed the else statement and its now return False...

Comment: Can you please 1) show your new else statement 2) show how you know the test should return true (ie, how to write 42 = ...) 3) add the line `print(nums)` right under `def num_ops(n, nums):` so we can see how the array `nums` evolves during the recursive calls and why it fails to find your solution on this test.

Comment: The output is quite long, I have only attached the first page. Thank you so much for your patience Stef!

Comment: In the else branch, putting the `return` statement inside the for loops won't work. The instruction `return` interrupts the function call, which means anything that should happen after it doesn't happen. For instance, `def f(n): for i in range(n): print(i) return i` (with the return aligned with the print) would only print `0`, because the first return would prevent it from printing 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 and 9.

Comment: A possible alternative would be: `else:  results = []  for ...: for ...: ... results.append(
                        num_ops(n, [a*b] + temp)
                        or num_ops(n, [a+b] + temp)
                        or num_ops(n, [a-b] + temp)
                        or (b != 0 and num_ops(n, [a/b] + temp))
                    )`. Now you have a list of `True` and `False`. You want to return `True` if it contains at least one `True`. This can be achieved with function `any()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any

Comment: Note that this alternative would be suboptimal because the for loop would try every possibility and not stop at the first True. But I suggest first getting a program that works; once it's working, you can optimize it.